# How to display word/pdf binary data in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework

I have a web application (written with angular) where the user can define a basic document structure and then click 'preview', when he does, a request is sent to the server, which returns a binary representation of the document.

I open a new browser window and I want to display the document there but i have no idea how to do it. The document can be in either Word (docx) or PDF format.

here are the response headers:

```
access-control-allow-headers: "X-Requested-With"
access-control-allow-origin: "*"
content-disposition: "attachment; filename=5/Test_Opportunity-my_quote-1-Feb-2015-13-16-42.docx"
content-length: "1105470"
content-security-policy: "default-src 'self';img-src data: 'self'  https://*.rackcdn.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://code.jquery.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://*.rackcdn.com 'unsafe-eval' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'self' ;style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://*.rackcdn.com  https://*.googleapis.com;font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com"
content-type: "application/x-download"
x-content-type-options: "nosniff"
x-frame-options: "DENY"
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: "master-only"
x-xss-protection: "1; mode=block"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just showing the raw document in it's own new window, the location of that window should be to the URL path that returns the binary document.  Something like:

```
<a href="...preview_request_to_server_url..." target="_blank">Preview</a>
```

You want to open a new window, and have that new window actually request the preview.

Comment: I guess another option if you don't want bookmarkable links or some other restriction, you could load the contents into your angular app, do a $window.open and use some javascript to shuffle the binary data to that new window.  I've never personally tried that.

Comment: Actually that's exactly my problem, i have a binary data that i need to convert to downloadable content, without the user being able to bookmark it.

Answer (score 1):

While downloading the files the content type should be like below.
Set their respective mimeTypes to their extension.

```
    extension and there content/mime Type

    .doc  = application/msword
    .docx = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    .pdf  = application/pdf
```

Refer [**MimeTypeList**](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-summary-list/)

And then use

```
$window.open('url', '_blank');
```

This will work on IE-9+. Thanks.